# How can I set the height and width of an element to the height and width of another element + a bit extra in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have these 3 Label elements whose text will change and I want the Rectangle elements to change their shape in order to fit the text.(Note: they need to be Rectangle, cannot use BoxView instead)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZa5Y.png)

I've managed to make the rectangle to fit the text perfectly but I can't make it to add some extra space. Here's the XAML code of one of the tags

```
                                            <Rectangle Fill="red"
                                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                   HeightRequest="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference TAG1}}" 
                                                   WidthRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference TAG1}}"/>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding tags[0]}"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               TextColor="White"
                                               FontFamily="Kanit"
                                               FontSize="12"
                                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                                               x:Name="TAG1"/>
```

Edit: [Here is what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dknzp.png)

Comment: Consider instead of `Rectangle`, wrapping the Label with a `Frame`. Another option is a single-cell `Grid` containing the Label. Then Label's `Margin` would do what you want.

Comment: Maybe I should have specified that I plan to make the rectangle transparent and only have the border colored, that's why I need to use Rectangle. I have tried using 2 frames, one colored and one gray to make a border but it just doesn't look good.

Comment: Little confused, and is [this](https://imgur.com/6c4szeW) what you wanna achieve?

Comment: I see you've added your solution to the question. Instead, please add that as Your Answer below. This makes it clear which is the question, which is the solution. You can accept your own answer after 48 hours pass.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targeting Xamarin, however, if you are targeting Maui. I think `Border` is much more flexible than `Frame` in Maui. With `Border` you can grant each corner an individual corner radius, stroke color and StrokeThickness...

```
<HorizontalStackLayout> 
        <Border
               StrokeThickness="2"
               Stroke="green"
               Padding="20"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Border.StrokeShape>
                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20"/>
            </Border.StrokeShape>

            <Label Text="TAG1"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="18"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </Border>

        <Border
               StrokeThickness="2"
               Stroke="green"
               Padding="20"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Border.StrokeShape>
                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20"/>
            </Border.StrokeShape>

            <Label Text="TAG2"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="18"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </Border>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

**Effect:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, although in a roundabout way, by putting the Label inside a Frame I was able to manipulate the size of the Frame how I wanted so I moved the reference from the Label to the Frame, made the frame transparent and used the Rectangle.

```
                                            <!--FirstTag -->
                                        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"
                                                   RadiusX="7"
                                                   RadiusY="7"
                                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                   HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference TAG1}, Path=Height}" 
                                                   WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference TAG1}, Path=Width}">
                                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#4DD599"
                                                                  Offset="0.1"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#00918E"
                                                                  Offset="1.0"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                        </Rectangle>

                                        <Frame Grid.Column="0"
                                               CornerRadius="10"
                                               HasShadow="False"
                                               Padding="7, 5, 7, 5"
                                               x:Name="TAG1"
                                               BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                            
                                               <Label Text="{Binding tags[0]}"
                                                      Grid.Column="0"
                                                      TextColor="White"
                                                      FontFamily="Kanit"
                                                      FontSize="12"
                                                      HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                      VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                        </Frame>
                                        <!--EndFirstTag-->
```